# How to check state of a child component in react in render function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am rendering two components SearchForm and RecentSearch like

```
var SearchFormContainer = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
        <div>
        <SearchForm />
        <RecentSearch />
        </div>      
    );;
  }
});
```

There is a state in SearchForm. Based on the state I want to render RecentSearch component. How can I check the state of SearchFrom? What I tried is:

```
var SearchFormContainer = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
        <div>
        <SearchForm ref="search_form"/>
        {this.refs.search_form.state ? <RecentSearch /> : null}
        </div>
    );
  }
});
```

this.refs.search_form.state returing undefined.

Answer (score 2):

Keep the state in the your parent container (`SearchFormContainer`). Update this state e.g. via a callback function you pass to your `SearchForm`. Something like this:

```
const Container = React.createClass({
  onSearch(value) {
    this.setState({search: value});
  }
  render() {
    <div>
      <SearchForm onSearch={this.onSearch} />
      <RecentSearch recentValue={this.state.search} />
    </div>
  }
});

const SearchForm = ({onSearch}) => {
  return (
    <input
      type="search"
      onChange={event => onSearch(event.target.value)}
    />
  );
}
```

Also I recommend this article by Dan Abromov about Smart & Dumb Components:
https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0#.qq4cufc2c

Hope this helps!

Comment: Totally agree, you should have your smart component that handles state, and passes whatever parameters or values it needs. Changing the search bar should update it's parents state.

Answer (score 0):

In React state is a component level concept, and works from the top down through the passing of props to child components, not really the other way around.

If you want to render your `RecentSearch` component based on the state of  `SearchForm` you could either add an extra layer of state to your `SearchFormContainer` component that basically keeps track of `SearchForm` submissions and conditionally renders `RecentSearch` based on that.

```
var SearchFormContainer = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function() {
    return { userHasSearched: false }
  },

  onSearchSubmit: function() {
    this.setState({ userHasSearched: true });
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        //Pass submit handler down to the SearchForm component
        <SearchForm onSubmit={this.onSearchSubmit} />
        {this.state.userHasSearched ? <RecentSearch /> : null}
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Or even better, remove the extra complexity that's introducing (unless you have a specific future intent for `SearchFormContainer`), and just return your `<RecentSearch />` component conditionally inside of `<SearchForm />`, where your state is actually located at the moment.